# 13.10 Samba installed. Cannot find it

Tags: 13.10, samba

I have freshly installed 13.10 on a laptop, I have done the obligatory web searches to find out all the things I need to install to actually make it useful.

One of those is to install `Samba`, which I believe is necessary to put this laptop on a home network, and enable Personal File Sharing.

I have tried installing samba from the Software Center, also via terminal with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get  install  samba samba-common
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
```

Running the above commands yields a message saying it is already installed. If I look in Software Center, it shows `Samba` as installed. I have also tried other variations of these from other websites, but the net result is that `Samba` IS installed.

Yet, I cannot find any icon for `Samba` in the Applications list and Personal File Sharing gives the message that network sharing is not available because certain packages (ie `samba`, right?) are not installed.  I have also found the Main Menu icon and ticked every single possible box, so if there is anything installed, there should be an icon for it in Applications.

So, what is going wrong?

Secondly, why in god's name does Ubuntu not simply install `Samba` in the first place??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> so, what is going wrong? secondly, why in god's name does Ubuntu not simply install Samba in the first place??

1. You are wrong. Do not blindly doing thing that you don't understand.
   Follow this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide).
2. Because not everyone uses samba.

Comment: thanks for the guide. i will give that a try.

note, however, that it is all very well to say 'dont blindly do things you dont understand', but if i dont understand them, i dont have any choice. especially when Ubuntu, as installed, wont connect to a home network without doing extra things.  it appears that enabling samba is necessary to join my home network, and enable Personal File Sharing.  ok so maybe Samba isnt required for all that.  so, what is the alternative?  however you look at it, Ubuntu should be able to connect to a home network out of the box.